# How to calculate the frequency of a class of numbers in R

Tags: r, frequency

I've been asked to generate a normal distribuition of 1000 numbers with mean=1000 and sd=4, and did it using rnorm(1000, mean=1000, sd=4). Now I have to calculate the frequency of numbers between 996 and 1004. How do I do it?

Comment: Sonny has the correct answer, incase you mean amount of numbers between those two intervals, try `a <- rnorm(1000, mean=1000, sd=4)` followed by `length(a[a >= 996 & a <= 1004])/length(a)`

Comment: Good luck on the rest of your homework.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much my man

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
a <- rnorm(1000, mean=1000, sd=4)
table(round(a[a >= 996 & a <= 1004], 0))
 996  997  998  999 1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 
  35   75   94   98  110   87   82   84   28
```

Comment: kind off, but you helped me with something I didn't know and also helped the other guy to get it right, I aprecciate it!